# Cumulative sum of a subset of data based on condition

Tags: r

I have what i think is a simple R task but i'm having trouble. Basically I need to do a cumulative sum of values based on the criteria of another column.

Here's the catch, it should do the cumulative sum for the previous rows until it hits another condition. In the example i'm providing, it accumulates all values from the duration column, 1 and 2 in the condition column. Example is shown below.

```
duration <- c(2,3,2,4,5,10,2,9,7,5,8,9,10,12,4,5,6)
condition <- c(0,1,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,2)
accum_sum <- c(0,5,0,0,0,0,0,32,0,0,0,0,39,0,0,0,27)

df <- data.frame(duration,condition,accum_sum)
df
row    duration condition accum_sum
1         2         0         0
2         3         1         5
3         2         0         0
4         4         0         0
5         5         0         0
6        10         0         0
7         2         0         0
8         9         2        32
9         7         0         0
10        5         0         0
11        8         0         0
12        9         0         0
13       10         1        39
14       12         0         0
15        4         0         0
16        5         0         0
17        6         2        27
```

Answer (score 4):

Using data.table:

```
setDT(df)
df[, accum_sum := cumsum(duration), by = rev(cumsum(rev(condition)))]
df[condition == 0, accum_sum := 0]
#    duration condition accum_sum
# 1:        2         0         0
# 2:        3         1         5
# 3:        2         0         0
# 4:        4         0         0
# 5:        5         0         0
# 6:       10         0         0
# 7:        2         0         0
# 8:        9         2        32
# 9:        7         0         0
#10:        5         0         0
#11:        8         0         0
#12:        9         0         0
#13:       10         1        39
#14:       12         0         0
#15:        4         0         0
#16:        5         0         0
#17:        6         2        27
```

We create runs by filling the zeros backwards with `rev(cumsum(rev(condition)))` and then group by this "filled" condition.

Comment: The double reverse is very clever.

Comment: `accum_sum := sum(duration)` would produce the same output.

Comment: I know. I haven't benchmarked `sum` with recycling vs `cumsum` but both should be of similar speed.

Answer (score 2):

```
#cumulative sum
df$cum_sum <- ave(df$duration, c(0, cumsum(df$condition[-nrow(df)])), FUN = cumsum)

#replace all zero condition row with zero value in cumulative sum column
df$cum_sum <- ifelse(df$condition == 0, 0, df$cum_sum)
```

which gives

```
   duration condition cum_sum
1         2         0       0
2         3         1       5
3         2         0       0
4         4         0       0
5         5         0       0
6        10         0       0
7         2         0       0
8         9         2      32
9         7         0       0
10        5         0       0
11        8         0       0
12        9         0       0
13       10         1      39
14       12         0       0
15        4         0       0
16        5         0       0
17        6         2      27
```

**Sample data:**

```
df <- structure(list(duration = c(2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 10, 2, 9, 7, 5, 8, 
9, 10, 12, 4, 5, 6), condition = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2), cum_sum = c(0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 32, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 39, 0, 0, 0, 27)), .Names = c("duration", "condition", 
"cum_sum"), row.names = c(NA, -17L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`, we can use `cumsum()` on `condition` to keep track of how many conditions have been seen. Then add within those subsets:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
    mutate(condition_group = cumsum(lag(condition, default = 0) != 0) + 1) %>%
    group_by(condition_group) %>%
    mutate(accum_sum = ifelse(condition != 0,
                              sum(duration),
                              0))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 17 x 4
# Groups:   condition_group [4]
   duration condition accum_sum condition_group
      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>           <dbl>
 1        2         0         0               1
 2        3         1         5               1
 3        2         0         0               2
 4        4         0         0               2
 5        5         0         0               2
 6       10         0         0               2
 7        2         0         0               2
 8        9         2        32               2
 9        7         0         0               3
10        5         0         0               3
11        8         0         0               3
12        9         0         0               3
13       10         1        39               3
14       12         0         0               4
15        4         0         0               4
16        5         0         0               4
17        6         2        27               4
```

Answer (score 0):

If you shift condition by 1, you can simply use tapply.

```
duration <- c(2,3,2,4,5,10,2,9,7,5,8,9,10,12,4,5,6)
condition <- c(0,1,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,2)
accum_sum <- c(0,5,0,0,0,0,0,32,0,0,0,0,39,0,0,0,27)

df <- data.frame(duration,condition,accum_sum)

df$want <- unlist(tapply(df$duration, 
                         INDEX = cumsum(c(df$condition[1], head(df$condition, -1))), 
                         cumsum)) * ifelse(df$condition == 0, 0, 1)
df
```